Genesys Cloud for Salesforce. Visualforce is empty
We are using Genesys Cloud for Salesforce and an issue has appeared when doing a custom design. Our use case is the following:
When a call is received the package makes a sosl in every phone field of every object and by setting up 'Softphone layout' in Salesforce we set the behaviour for no records found, single record found and multiple matching records found. In the multiple matching records we have selected a visualforce which by an apex controller makes some calculations and then calls a screen flow. So if 2 records have the caller's number in one of their fields a screenflow opens with a list of the records and you can choose one of those. Our problem is that we don't want to use the sosl that the package makes because there are certain phone fields that shouldn't be searched.
To void that standard behaviour we are using an Extension Point. The extension point is an apex class that implements an interface which tells the system to avoid the standard search and use the custom. Our problem is the extension point apex class we make a query to the specific fields we want to search and for one of the cases (multiple records found) it calls the visualforce page. The visualforce page is loaded without records, even though records have been found and it should be populated.
Has any one worked with Extension Points and knows how to populate the visualforce?
Below you can find the visualforce's apex controller class and the Extension Point class
**Apex controller:**

public class FlowRedirectController {

public PageReference redirectToFlow() {

// Obtén el parámetro de la página actual

String phone = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('key');

// Construye el argumento del flujo con el parámetro

String flowArgs = '[{"name":"Phone","type":"String","value":"' + phone + '"}]';

// Codifica el argumento para la URL

String encodedFlowArgs = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(flowArgs, 'UTF-8');

// Construye la URL del flujo en Lightning Experience

String flowUrl = '/lightning/page/recordActionFlow?lightning__flowDevName=CTI_ScreenFlow_GestionDeContactosMultiples&lightning__flowArgs=' + encodedFlowArgs + '&lightning__isMandatory=false&lightning__isServiceCatalogFlow=false';

// Redirige a la URL del flujo en Lightning

PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(flowUrl);

pageRef.setRedirect(true);

return pageRef;

}

}

External point class:

global class MyCTIExtensions implements purecloud.CTIExtension.ScreenPop{

public String onScreenPop(String data){

Map screenPopData = (Map) JSON.deserializeUntyped(data);

Map dataToReturn = new Map();

String phoneNumber = (String) screenPopData.get('searchValue');

if (String.isNotBlank(phoneNumber)){

String phone = '%910...';

List cases = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Phone LIKE :phone ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC];

if(cases.size() > 1) {

dataToReturn.put('url','/lightning/page/recordActionFlow?lightning__flowArgs=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22Phone%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22String%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22null%22%7D%5D&lightning__flowDevName=CTI_ScreenFlow_GestionDeContactosMultiples&lightning__isMandatory=false&lightning__isServiceCatalogFlow=false' /cases.get(0).Id/);

return JSON.serialize(dataToReturn);

}else if (cases.size() > 0) {

dataToReturn.put('url',cases.get(0).Id);

return JSON.serialize(dataToReturn);

}

}

dataToReturn.put('defaultScreenPop', true);

return JSON.serialize(dataToReturn);

}

}

Thanks for your help.
